# Troubleshoot in Microsoft Azure Application Insight regarding on limitation of ajax request

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-hub

I am unable to troubleshoot in Microsoft Azure Application Insight regarding exception of limitation of Ajax request which occurred when fired a request for my WEB URL and got a response as "Request time out". The actual exception message is given below which I found inside Azure...

> Maximum ajax per page view limit reached, ajax monitoring is paused
>   until the next trackPageView(). In order to increase the limit set the
>   maxAjaxCallsPerView configuration parameter." props:"true"

I couldn't find any solution regarding on above message.Please help with the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consult with Microsoft Azure provider regarding that issue.
Also, I am sending you a link for your reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-javascript

Comment: Thanks for share above link and  I am getting here the same problem regarding Ajax request issue. This article is helpful.